# D3.js nested data - how can i display my circles

Tags: d3.js

I am a beginner on D3.js and hit the wall on the following:

I wish to display the score given by an attendee of an event over time. Then as the attendee can give also comments, I would like to place a circle on the curve of the score in the same colour as the scoring.
I succeeded to do this for a single user.

The code is on JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/roestigraben/8s1t8hb3/

Then, trying to extend this to multiple attendees, I run into problems.

The JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/roestigraben/Lk2kf1gh/

This code displays nicely the score data for the 3 attendees simulated. However the circles to display the possible comments (there is only one in the data set) from the attendees do not work
I try to filter the attendees array
    svg.selectAll("circle")

```
 .data(data.filter(function(d, i){ if(d.comment){return d}; })) // condition here
 .enter().append("circle")
 .attr("class", "dotLarge")
 .attr({r: 5})
 .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.time); })
 .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.status); })
```

I think I need to go deeper into the nesting, but ....my ignorance.
Thanks a lot

Peter

Comment: So what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Hey Lars, I am looking for having the behaviour as on the first JSFiddle example extended now for multiple data sets. The 2nd JSFiddle is showing the multiple lines, but I lack the circles on it whenever a comment key/value pair is in the data set.

Comment: Well the second fiddle doesn't look anything like the first -- the axes etc are missing. Is that intentional?

Comment: yes, I started just as a test to understand how to plot multiple lines with my special circles for the comments. Can you give me a breakthru hint so i can progress, I am really stuck here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The code where you're displaying your circles doesn't even come close to matching the format of your data.  I don't know that you're having a problem with the nest, but you probably want a slightly different data structure when it comes to graphing your comments.

I have updated your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Lk2kf1gh/7/

The important bit is:

```
var comments = attendees.map(function(d) {
     return {
         name: d.name,
         comments: d.values.filter(function(e) {
             return e.comment != undefined;
         })
     };
 });

 //generation of the circles to indicate a comment
 // needs to be done with a filter
 svg.selectAll("g.comments")
     .data(comments)
   .enter()
     .append("g")
     .attr("class", function(d) { return "comments " + d.name })
     .selectAll("circle.comment")
       .data(function(d) {
           return d.comments;
       })
     .enter()
       .append("circle")
       .attr("class", "dotLarge comment")
       .attr("r", 5)
       .attr("cx", function(e) { return x(e.time); })
       .attr("cy", function(e) { return y(e.status); });
```

The first part of this code creates a new data structure that is more focused on the comment information.  The second part creates the circles.

Note: I've grouped each person into their own `g` element and then created a circle for each of their comments.  This makes use of `d3` nested selections and data binding.  Hopefully you can follow what is happening.

I've also added a few more comments to your data for testing.  I didn't bother to fix any of the cosmetic issues, I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: Many thanks for this. I suppose in the new data structure, you are passing the data into the function as "e". Remaining question is: how can I force the color chosen for the line also for the comments ? Anyway, many thanks for your help.

Comment: I could resolve the color issue as well.I did add the line .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); }) to g group and it did the job. So, all set for now.